# Is it possible to write Groovy tests with Arquillian/Drone/Graphene

Tags: groovy, coded-ui-tests, jboss-arquillian, drone.io, graphene2

I'm writing function UI tests and  need to know does Arquillian/Drone/Graphene frameworks support Groovy tests.

I'm finding it hard to find information online.
Can groovy be implemented in this way or should is it easier to stick with Spock and Geb for groovy tests?

Comment: If they use Java, I would think you could write them in Groovy.

Comment: I dont understand your requirement. Your tests will be in Groovy and page objects in Java/graphene?

Comment: I'm doing research for UI web automated tests, I've set up a arquillian, drone and graphene project which the tests are written in groovy, I also set up a spock and Geb where the tests are written in Groovy. Now I've been asked to set up arquillian, drone and graphene to use groovy tests but I'm not sure what layer do i even go about to add in a groovy extension. Does drone run with groovy? Or do i add a spock-arquillian extension? really not sure

Comment: yes, arquillian has spock extension - take a look. provide some more info for better answer.